# How to write the log in the TWE task script running in CMDBuild?

Tags: cmdb

I'm using TWE (Together Workflow Editor) to write XPDL file with the java code. The file is imported into CMDBuild.

I follow the example of OpenMaint.

```
logger.debug("action {}", Action);
```

However, I couldn't find the debug log in the cmdbuild.log. It runs without error.
How to let it export to the log file?

By the way, is there a way to debug the code in the script?